# How to manipulate elements in an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, image, html-parsing, associative-array

I've an associative array titled `$feeds` (after executing `print_r($feeds);`) as follows :

Note: The actual associative array `$feeds` is very large. For the understanding purpose I've only put one element from the huge array.

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
         [feed_image] => Array
         (
           [0] => <a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/928/2_onclick_ok/userid_244/"  class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="928" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555_240.jpg"  alt=""  width="180"  height="160"  class="photo_holder" /></a><br />
           [1] => <a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/927/8/userid_244/" class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="927"><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429_240.png"  alt="" height="84" width="150"  class="photo_holder"  userid="244" /></a>
         )
      )
    )
```

First of all I want to check whether the key `['feed_image']` is present in an associative array $feeds. If it's present convert the array `$feeds['feed_image']` by changing the image path of each array element as follows :

I want to create the new array from 'src' attribute's value of each `<img>` tag. You can observe in this case too.

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
         [feed_image] => Array
         (
           [0] => 2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555%s.jpg
           [1] => 2015/04/2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429%s.png
         )
      )
    )
```

I tried following code but it didn't work. It returns nothing.

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($feeds as $key => $value) {
 if (is_array($feeds[$cnt]['feed_image'])) {
    $feeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key] = (string) reset(simplexml_import_dom(DOMDocument::loadHTML($feeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key]))->xpath("//img/@src"));
  }
$cnt++;
}
```

Comment: 1. From which values do you create the new array? 2. Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 : 1. I want to create the new array from src attribute's value of each <img> tag. You can observe in above case too. 2. This is an entirely new thing for me, so I've no idea about how to achieve this.

Comment: Just *try* something until you fail. This could be do some research and show us what you have found OR write some code and try it OR write some pseudo code to get a concept, just show some effort and work! (SO is not a code writing service! Also if we see your work it's easier to see where you failed, so that we know what we have to explain better so that you understand it and learn it easily)

Comment: @Rizier123 : I've added my efforts at the end of question body but still it didn't work out for me. Please help me.

Comment: I advise against adding "please help me" to comments or questions here - it is sometimes seem as a form of begging. Questions will be answered in good time.

Comment: It is good that you have made an attempt, and illustrated it. However you appear to have put five functions or so on the same line, so it is not possible to debug (and I guess you have not tried). Split this out over several lines, starting with `$html = $feeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key];`, then `$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);` etc. You can then use `echo` statements to examine where it goes wrong.